# How can I change my IMAP e-mail address in Outlook and retain all my emails and folders?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

I'm using **Outlook 2010**.  I want to change my e-mail address from name@domain1.com to name@domain2.net.

Both e-mail addresses sync with the mail server via IMAP.

I can change the email address and server setting in Outlook in the **Account Settings**.

But as soon as I change from name@domain1.com to name@domain2.net, Outlook syncs to the new mail server (which is empty) and removes all my directories and email from the old email address.

Is there a way to get name@domain2.net to mirror name@domain1.com without having to migrate all the mails from server to sever *outside* of Outlook?

Comment: Create a local .PST file.   Copy the files from the IMAP Server to the .PST Archive.  This will allow you to keep a local copy of the emails.  An optional step copy the emails to the new IMAP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAP doesn't keep a local copy.

You will have to merge the emails manually, but this can be done *inside* Outlook by either

Creating 2 IMAP accounts in Outlook, and then copying the files over  (dragging the emails from one account to the other)

Creating a new POP3 Account, download all the emails, change over the IMAP account details, and then copy the emails across